# android:button="@null" doesn't work on lower API <= 19 devices

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-button, androidx

I updated the version of the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` to `1.1.0-alpha01` for use [new features](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha01). But after the update, the `android:button="@null"`  with the RadioButton stopped working on devices lower API 19 and doesn't delete the default radio icon. Any solutions ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case worked only with both

```
        android:button="@null"
        app:buttonCompat = "@null"
```

attributes set to @null

Comment: Any Idea about how to set this  programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. Looks like after upgrading appcompact you now have to use

```
 `app:buttonCompat="@null"`
```

Got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631014/after-migration-to-androidx-androidbutton-is-not-respected-for-api-below-lollip)