# After migration to AndroidX android:button is not respected for API below Lollipop

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

I have very simple checkbox:

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/clipboardBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/clipboard_checkbox" />
```

For checked/unchecked I have two different images.

After migration to AndroidX I see default image for Android on devices below API 21.

What I've tried already:

- change CheckBox to AppCompatCheckbox (from AndroidX) - nothing changed
- set background to checkbox & set `android:button="@null"` - background is OK, but I still see default image on background (see image below)

Seems that Android completly disrespect `button` attribute.

[image: example of background set to img and button to null]

I am out of ideas. For Lollipop+ everythink works as it should. Have anyone faced issue like this?
Only change I did was migration to AndroidX :/

Comment: Upon a quick glance at the source, it looks like `AppCompatCheckbox` uses the `buttonCompat` attribute instead. That'll be in your app's namespace, btw; i.e., `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, `app:buttonCompat="@drawable/clipboard_checkbox"`.

Comment: Actually, now that I look again, it should fall back to the regular `button` attribute if `buttonCompat` isn't there. That might be a bug, if reliably reproducible.

Comment: ^ I will check it in about 1h and I'll let you known! :)

Comment: Oh, hold on a second. Lollipop, you say? Are your images vector drawables, by chance?

Comment: Nope. I'm using images (png) only.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I'll try to run some tests later on, too, if I get a chance.

Comment: Setting `app:buttonCompat` instead of `android:button` worked! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change CheckBox to AppCompatCheckBox(AndroidX) and replace **android:button to app:buttonCompat**

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/clipboardBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
    app:buttonCompat="@drawable/clipboard_checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In the appcompat theme, the checkBoxStyle below API 21 is defined as

```
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:button">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
        <item name="buttonCompat">?attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultipleAnimated</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/controlBackground</item>
    </style>
```

the attr buttonCompat has a default value to show the click animation. The attr buttonCompat take effect and ignore the button attr.

To fix it, the attr buttonCompat must be undefined. In your theme add

```
    <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckBox</item>
```

and add a style

```
    <style name="MyCheckBox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:button">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
        <item name="buttonCompat">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
    </style>
```

Also in your values-v21 dir, add this to your theme

```
    <item name="checkboxStyle">?android:attr/checkboxStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the button and buttonCompat null for androidx libraries. It will look like below-

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@null"
                app:buttonCompat="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/cb_pause_resume_selector"
                />
```

Comment: Shivam's answer is the one that worked for us, thank you