# Why does androidx.preference library stop my custom checkboxes from displaying properly?

Tags: android, user-interface, gradle, kotlin, androidx

I've decided to update my Options activity to androidx.preference. So I added `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0'` to my dependencies. However, now my custom checkboxes from elsewhere in my app no longer use the custom button given to them and just use the default checkbox.**(Note: this only happens on devices running Android 4.4 or lower)**

Removing `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0'` fixes the issue. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can overcome it?

---

in activity layout:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbSharePosition"
        style="@style/ActionCenter.Light.CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:checked="true"/>
```

in style_widgets.xml:

```
<style name="ActionCenter.Light.CheckBox" parent="android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/actioncenter_switch_button</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
</style>
```

actioncenter_switch_button.xml:

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on"
   android:state_checked="true" />

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off"
   android:state_checked="false" />

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" />
   </selector>
```

Comment: Maybe an extension function in preferences-ktx is shadowing something of your own. What if you use the standard java dependency without the ktx?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Same result :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be issue in `1.1.0` version of `Appcompat` library. 
You can use `buttonCompat` attribute instead `button` and everything should work fine.

You can replace:

```
<item name="android:button">@drawable/actioncenter_switch_button</item>
```

with:

```
<item name="buttonCompat">@drawable/actioncenter_switch_button</item>
```

[After migration to AndroidX android:button is not respected for API below Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631014/after-migration-to-androidx-androidbutton-is-not-respected-for-api-below-lollip)